# Including FFTW and CUDA(or any other library) in project on GitHub

Tags: c++, github, version-control, libraries

I'm developing a Speech Recognition library in C++ and want to use FFTW for DFT and DCT, and CUDA for paralel HMM. Can I put necessary include files and .dll from those two libraries on GitHub? If I can, is that a good practice, or should I assume that whoever is building my project have those libraries installed on their machine?